# Flutter : How to do state management for sign up with different screens and render accordingly?

Tags: flutter, navigation, state

Flutter : If I want to sign up and there are three screens to collect the sign up information like

First screen has fields to collect name, mobile number.

Second screen has fields to collect college name, upload doc,

Third screen for taking preferences.

The only things changing are the content of the card. How should I manage the state and navigate or render components accordingly for such a scenario?

Comment: you can use the `pageview` widget and state management technique to achieve your requirement.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you mean like a custom Textfield or a widget to take input from user like username and password and email but you don't want to write the same code again and again then you can create a separate widget and call it when u need it and change some or all of its properties. here is a custom textfield code and how to call it

```
class textbox extends StatefulWidget {
  textbox({
    Key key,
    @required this.height,
    @required this.width,
    @required this.hint,
    this.v1,
    this.callback,
    this.p1,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final ValueSetter<String> callback;
  String v1;
  final String hint;
  bool p1 = false;
  final double height;
  final double width;

  @override
  _textboxState createState() => _textboxState();
}

class _textboxState extends State<textbox> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: widget.height * 0.08,
      width: widget.width * 0.75,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
        color: Colors.white60,
        border: Border.all(width: 1.0),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: const Color(0x29000000),
            offset: Offset(0, 3),
            blurRadius: 6,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
            width: widget.width * 0.65,
            child: TextFormField(
              obscureText: widget.p1,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: widget.hint, border: InputBorder.none),
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  widget.v1 = val;
                  widget.callback(this.widget.v1);
                });
              },
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is how you call it

```
textbox(
                              height: height,
                              width: width,
                              hint: 'Password',
                              p1: true,
                              callback: (v1) {
                                signpassword = v1;
                              },
                            )
```

or in username case

```
textbox(
                            height: height,
                            width: width,
                            hint: 'username',
                            p1: false,
                            callback: (v1) {
                              signusername = v1;
                            },
                          ),
```

Comment: No I didnt mean that. I meant is it a better apprach to have three screens and navigate between them? Or should I just change the component(the card) which has those textboxes accordingly? If I should change components then how can I manage the state i.e when I press next, the second component should show up, and if I press abck again the first component should show up